# Overly abstract types in an interface

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

I'm trying to learn Kotlin, but I find it quite a counter intuitive language.
One big struggle is that Kotlin doesn't have any sort of general monad concept.  So I figured as a exercise to help me learn the language I would implement a monad `interface`, and maybe I'd be able to use it a little bit too.

As an example here is a maybe we will be using:

```kotlin
sealed class Maybe<T>
class Nothing<T> : Maybe<T>()
data class Just<T>(val getJust: T) : Maybe<T>()
```

So now to make some interfaces, we will fill in the functions later

```kotlin
interface Functor<T>

interface Applicative<T> : Functor<T>

interface Monad<T> : Applicative<T>
```

Ok so I start with `Functor`

```kotlin
interface Functor<T> {
    fun <K> map(f: (T) -> K): Functor<K>
}
```

Now if we try and implement this we already have an issue, I want to enforce that `map` returns the same sort of functor it is a member to.  But all I can say is that it returns *some* thing that implements the `Functor<K>` interface.

Now this isn't *that* bad since we can just ask anyone that implements the interface to use the same type for the return.  The interface is only useful this way so they will likely oblige.  However when we get to the `Applicative` things get real dicey.

```kotlin
interface Applicative<T> : Functor<T> {
    fun <K> ap(m2: Applicative<(T) -> K>): Applicative<K> 
}
```

If I try to implement this for `Just` we have a problem (I'll skip over `Nothing` since it is a bit boring):

```kotlin
data class Just<T>(val getJust: T) : Maybe<T>() {
    override fun <K> map(f: (T) -> K): Just<K> {
        return Just(f(getJust))
    }
    override fun <K> ap(m2: Maybe<(T) -> K>): Maybe<K> {
        return when (m2) {
            is Nothing<(T) -> K> -> Nothing()
            is Just<(T) -> K> -> {
                Just(m2.getJust(getJust))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me that I didn't implement `ap` and `ap` overrides nothing.  What gives?  Well my `Applicative` interface actually requires that `ap` work on *any* `Applicative` not just the same one I am implementing for.  Apart from a few select applicative functors this is not possible.

Is there some way I can have fix this interface so that it doesn't require taking an arbitrary `Applicative`?

Comment: Have you looked into Arrow? You could get some inspiration about how to build this stuff in Kotlin https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow

Comment: “I find it quite a counter intuitive language” — What's your background?  What languages/platforms has your intuition been gained from?

Comment: @gidds I'm not sure, I'd say my intuitions come from Haskell I guess. I originally learned to program writing ASM on an variation Intel 8080. But I've mostly programmed in C++ and Haskell.  I've dabbled in others but those are the two I would say I've put the most time into.  I've virtually never written any Java which I think is what most Kotlin programmers come from.

Comment: Where optionals or maybes might be used in other languages, Kotlin's standard library uses nullable types. A value of nothing is null. A non-nullable type indicates a gauranteed value. There is also a Result class which can wrap a nullable type or an error, but the language restricts you from using it as a return value from your own functions because they haven't settled on some features of the class yet.

Comment: For instance, if you get a value from a `Map<String, Int>`, the returned value is an `Int?`. If the value is null, that means there was nothing in the map for the key you gave. But Kotlin's standard library is like functional programming-lite. It's still geared more towards Java-like code style. See Arrow for a library that is geared towards using Kotlin for functional programming.

Comment: The _error_ here is that Kotlin expects your definition of `ap` to accept _any_ `Applicative<(T) -> K>`, not just a `Maybe<(T) -> K>`.  Kotlin -- like Java -- doesn't have higher-order types -- you can't have `T1<T2>`, basically, where `T1` and `T2` are both type variables.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I understand nullable types maybe here is an example of a monad used for demonstration purposes because of its simplicity.

Comment: I’m not saying it’s an exact replacement for monads. It’s just the more typical way of doing this sort of thing in Kotlin. And this is not as common in Java. Since Java doesn’t have null-safe operators and inline scope functions, null checking is more cumbersome than in Kotlin.